# How can change session value on button click?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have the following code which shows some data from mysql in table format. I want when one clicks the button in that row...data in that row is saved in a session variable which will be used in the next page. Each button has an ID assigned from the while loop count.

```
 <div id="container">
    <table>     
<tr style="background: #372F2F;">
<th>Bus</th>
<th>From</th>
<th>To</th>
<th>Depart Time</th>
<th>Fare</th>
<th></th>
</tr> 
            <?php
            $ticket=array();
            $i=0;
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $ticket[$i][0]= $bus;
                $ticket[$i][1]= $from;
                $ticket[$i][2]= $to;
                $ticket[$i][3]= $depart;
                $ticket[$i][4]= $fare;
               ?>
<tr>
    <td  style="width: 200px"><?php printf ("%s", $bus); ?></td>
    <td  style="width: 200px"><?php printf ("%s", $from); ?></td>
    <td  style="width: 200px"><?php printf ("%s", $to); ?></td>
    <td  style="width: 200px"><?php printf ("%s", $depart); ?></td>
    <td  style="width: 100px"><?php printf ("%s", $fare); ?></td>
        <td style="width: 100px">
<div class="button red center" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" onclick="window.location='tickset.php'">Book Ticket</div>          
        </td>
</tr> 

 <?php
   $i++;
    }
    $_SESSION['ticket'] = $ticket;
?>        
            </table>
            <?php
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        } else {
            trigger_error('Statement failed : ' . $stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        ?>


  </div>
```

Comment: You need to use ajax for sending request from client to server.

Comment: Any help  please because i am a junior

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anchor` tags with `href` to your `tickset.php` page and pass the value along with it...the value you are trying to store as session...
Something like this..

```
<?php 
    echo '<a href="tickset.php?v='$value'">Value</a>';
?>
```

On the next page (`tickset.php`) you can get this value by simply using `GET`

```
$val = $_GET['v'];
```

You can then use this value...without the need of `session` variable...if in case you need to use it further..you can then store it as a `session variable` then on this page...

Comment: The table shows rows of data with a button at the end. How can I track the users button click and save the data along that row to be used in the next page...thanks.. @Moid Mohd

Comment: Try something like this...
`<?php 
echo '<td  style="width: 200px"><a href="tickset.php?'$value'">'.$bus.'</a></td>';
?>`

Comment: Just curious...have you done you assignment in the right way...?If `$bus` stores the value then it should on the left...

Comment: Table is as follows and I want to pick the values in the row for some algorithm in the next page.
http://2-invest.webuda.com/st.png  @ Moid Mohd

Comment: Do it like this...
`<td style="width: 100px"><div class="button red center" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><a href="tickset.php?v=<?php echo $value; ?>">Book Ticket</a></div></td>`.. here `$value` is the data that you want to pass(constant or dynamic).. Now you can get this value on next page by a simple `GET` request..as I have explained in my answer...
You can get rid of div and simply style your `anchor` to look like button

Comment: It works but how do I pass on an array it looks like it just shows me array when i try to print_r($val);  @Moid Mohd

Comment: What are you trying to send? If you are trying to send an array, then send individual data with every button...

Comment: Sorry I have been on a trip but thank you very much it all worked out well for me. @Moid Mohd